# Files are closed before reaching the end - using ExitStack in Python

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

I have used the following code to read multiple files simultaneously

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

files_to_parse = [file1, file2, file3]
    
with ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(i, "r")) for i in files_to_parse]
    for rows in zip(*files):
        for r in rows:
            #do stuff
```

However I have noticed that since all my files don't have the same number of lines, whenever the shortest file reaches the end, all the files will close.

I used the code above (which I found here on stackoverflow) because I need to parse several files at the same time (to save time). Doing so, divide the computing time by 4. However all files aren't parsed entirely because of the problem I have mentioned above.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Please update your question with the code that is reading the files.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have updated the question with code, hope that is enough..

Comment: Ok, so you are using `zip()`, so the loop will stop on the first exhausted file. What would it mean to your code if the loop continued? Did you try `zip_longest()`?

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this function @quamrana! This has solved my problem.
I never used `zip()` so I didn't know that there would be an issue if all variables weren't of the same length.

Answer (score 0):

[`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) might be used as context manager, but does not have to. You might use it in ancient way, where you take responsibility to `close` it, that is

```
try:
    files = [open(fname) for fname in filenames]
    # here do what you need to with files
finally:
    for file in files:
        file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The problem I had, lied in the use of `zip()`. I was mistaken when I thought the problem was the way I was opening the files.